# .Net smtp SendMailAsync function returns IsCanceled

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the `SendMailAsync` routine. In the `ContinueWith()` Method
I am using `SendMailContinuation()` Method in which the `task.IsCanceled` always true.

.Net version  4.6.1

```
private void SendEMail()
{
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(EmailServerAddress))
        {
            _logger.Info("Sending Email to: {0} ", recipient);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(EmailAddress, EmailAddress, Encoding.UTF8),
                        to = new MailAddress(recipient, recipient, Encoding.UTF8);
            
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to))
            {
                message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                message.Body = "";
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, UserPassword);
            
                smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message)
                        .ContinueWith(SendMailContinuation);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);
    }
}
private void SendMailContinuation(Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        _logger.Error(task.Exception);
    }
    else if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        _logger.Warn(task.Status);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `await` `async` calls

Answer (score 0):

You should await the smtpClient.SendMailAsync() function. You can do this by making the function 'SendEMail()' an async task and adding await before the smtpClient.SendMailAsync() call.

Comment: It would probably help OP's understanding if you also explained why the task needs to be awaited in this case.